# Nginx to log the full response sent out and also log the response received from fastcgi without lua

Tags: nginx, logging, fastcgi

I have an issue where the Nginx after receiving the output from fastcgi server is missing the character. Is it possible to log the complete response received from Fastcgi server and also log the complete response sent out from Nginx webserver out.

I do not have lua module included.

Can you please provide the nginx.conf file which can do the same.

I had set fast_cgi_temp directive to log to temp file, but the temp file is empty.